# How to get the listener of the current build jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to get the listener of the current build in Jenkins and I am trying to get the `TaskListener` in my class which extends `Trigger<BuildableItem>` but I have no idea how to proceed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

The listeners and Launcher in Jenkins can be only obtained while a project is building. If you are trying to get them while executing the plugin which is not possible.